# Converting __block NSString to NSString (and eventually to std::string)

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

```
+(std::string)somefunc{
    __block NSString *vals = nil;
    [[Something somecall] completion:^(some params){vals=@"yay"}];
    return std::string([vals UTF8String]);
}
```

This function call throws an error "-[__NSMallocBlock__ UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x------"

Based on the way I've converted NSStrings in the past, I'm assuming this is something to do with my need to declare the NSString as a __block to modify it inside the []. But I could not find an answer anywhere.

What is the "best" way to convert it?

Comment: Is that closure invoked synchronously? The “completion” label implies it is asynchronous.

Comment: A `__block NSString *` is just an `NSString *` that can be manipulated from inside a block. That wouldn't need any converting, so the problem is something else. The error you're getting suggests that you've actually assigned a block to the `vals` variable instead of a string. Could you post some working code that we can run directly and reproduce the issue? As written above, it looks like `vals` would be likely to be `nil` at the time you call `-UTF8String` on it, since if the `completion` block is called asynchronously, it probably won't have run by the time your function returns.

Comment: The above won't compile; no semicolon after the variable assignment in the block.  But at runtime, the vals object is being set to a block instance, not an NSString, and it's obviously being changed after the variable is initially set to nil.  So something is going on separate from the posted code.